# Active X Command Buttons with Second Display

Tags: excel, vba, activex

I put Active X Command Buttons in an Excel Workbook.  They work just fine when the workbook is displayed on the primary monitor, but not when the workbook is displayed on the secondary monitor.  How do I fix this?

I'm not sure if it is hardware specific, but I run a MS Surface Pro 5.  At home it is connected to a Surface Dock with two monitors; the device screen is duplicated to one monitor (primary) and the desktop is extended to the other.  On-the-go I use a portable monitor thru the Mini Display Port.  The problem occurs in both configurations.

Answer (score 3):

Goto: File->Options->General-> under 'When using multiple displays' select 'Optimize for compitaility (application restart required)'

Answer (score 1):

Brad, I had the same problem where the activex buttons became unclickable when get connected to the secondary display. The problem is solely because of the varied resolutions. Ensure that the secondary monitor has the same resolution as that of primary monitory. In my case, my secondary monitor was a projector and I changed its resolution to 1366x768 which is what being used in the laptop. It then worked.

Comment: Karthick,  Thanks for the reply, I will go back and play with resolutions.  This makes sense because the Surface Pro's aspect ratio is closer to that of a square than a normal monitor. (3:2 vs. 16:9)

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately I had the same issue. It's not related to hardware, but software. If you change the resolution of the screen or projector (in my case), the active x buttons are starting to grow and deform.

The solution what I used is, to run this code on every active x action (just make a `call` for the `sub`), to make sure the buttons/labels etc are on their right place.

```
Set wbkWorkbook1 = ThisWorkbook

Set Rng = wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("WS1").Range("A14:F15")
wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("WS1").BTN.Width = Rng.Width
wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("WS1").BTN.Height = Rng.Height
wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("WS1").BTN.Left = wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("WS1").Range(wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("WS1").BTN.TopLeftCell.Address).Left
wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("WS1").BTN.Top = wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("WS1").Range(wbkWorkbook1.Worksheets("WS1").BTN.TopLeftCell.Address).Top
```

What this code makes: In this example we have an active X button labelled '**BTN**' on the worksheet named '**WS1**'. 
Once this script runs it aligns the BTN into the **A14:F15** range.

So if you change the resolution and runs this code, your active x controls will be re-adjusted.

You can go through on all controls with a `do ... loop until` procedure for sure.

Comment: sdda, thanks for the response.  My problem isn't so much that the buttons change size, but that they flat out don't work.  Drag workbook to main display and everything works fine; drag it over to the second display, and you can no longer click the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I deal with the same issue in a computer a couple months ago, I ended changing the  ActiveX buttons to the form controls ones, a couple days ago, same thing happen, BUT this time i find along with the IT Supports for the company i work for, that you have to match the SCREEN SCALE on all the monitors you have connected, and that should solve the problem..

I know, is stupid, but that's the solution..

Answer (score 0):

Another issue that can cause this problem (at least in Excel 2016 which is the version I am using) is when you open a second view window and you attempt to click the Active X control button when the active window is not window 1. If you navigate back to window 1 and select the sheet with button and click on it, it will work.

As others have said in this and other posts related to this issue, using form control buttons wont have this issue, but you need to put the code into a module and link the form button to the subroutine in said module. However, I am always a bit leary of putting code that is meant for a specific worksheet in a module rather than on the worksheet itself, but that's just me, I'm not the strongest VBA programmer so I always struggle with ensuring the code is working on the correct objects.